# TexStudio won't compile

Tags: miktex, texstudio

I just installed protext for my win 7 (64bit) OS. I have mixtex sucessfully installed and TeXstudio.

For some reason I can't compile documents with TeXstudio. If I write minimal tex document and press "Compile" I doesn't do anything. "Build and view" also doesn't do anything.

I can compile documents normally with TeXWorks thought. Do I have to teach TeXstudio where to find MikTex or something?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Related: http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/139655

Comment: You probably installed TeX Studio *before*  MiKTeX. If that is the case, uninstall TeX Studio and re-install it.

Comment: Well that was easy. Thanks! I knew I wasn't supposed to but I guess I had a brain freeze during install.

Answer (score 1):

Installing TeXStudio is not the same as installing the LaTeX distribution. They are independent and you need both of them to use LaTeX in TeXStudio.